# Calling ToUpper(s) in wsdl2js

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, web-services, wsdl

I'm using [wsdl2js](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2js/) to try and access a web service within JavaScript. I'm trying to start off simple, so I just have the following

```
function callws(){ 
    var ws = new Service1("http://server/TextMyBusService.wsdl");
    ws.ToUpper(document.getElementById("getCurrentBusPositions").value);
}
```

This is giving me the following errors in Chrome

```
GET http://server/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
```

When I use Firebug in Firefox, it tells me the first error is a line in my jQuery (the latest jQuery)

```
i.send(c.hasContent && c.data || null), d = function (a, e) {
```

but does not mentioned any jQuery error. The second error is from the wsdl2js source I downloaded, so I'm inclined to believe that it might not be an error and that it might hopefully fix itself if the first error is fixed. Nonetheless, here is the reference to line

```
var resultNode = rawdata.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;
```

I'm not 100% sure how to implement wsdl2js, apart from the sample code given in the zip I can't find many resources online that deal with my current issue. If I could get some pointers on implementing wsdl2js it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have `"http://server/TextMyBusService.wsdl"`, it looks like that's not your code because the requested resource is `"http://server/[object%20Object]"`

Comment: @Esailija the server is my account on my college's server so I'm not sure if I should give the full path, that's all. I do have full access to it though.

Comment: are you building the url-string dynamically? Perhaps you should check first if you are really accessing the right ressource.

Comment: That's not relevant, the issue is that you give impression that you have a string literal but in actuality you are concatenating a string and some object. Can you give the real code with anonymized urls and such?

Comment: @Christoph, nope the url is hard coded in. When I open the url in the browser I can view it with no problems.

Comment: @Esailija this is the exact code I'm running actually - bar the url. I'm trying to build it up so I have less problems (ironic) so I haven't added anything past these lines. I can provide you with the Service1 code if it would be helpful. Thanks for the replies